# App not working in LineageOS because "device is rooted or jail broken"

Tags: lineageos

I have a Pixel 4 XL that I just installed LineageOS on. One app is telling me it won't work because my device is rooted or jailbroken.

I'm guessing that this is related to the device being OEM unlocked? I did no other steps beyond installing LineageOS and Google Play services according to the LineageOS wiki installation pages for the device.

Is there any way to get around this?

Comment: Have you installed Google Play Services? If yes, then most likely the app make use of Google SafetyNet check or Google Play Integrity check and as you ROM is a custom ROM it can't be verified which means it fails at least one of the tests. The app can detect that and declares you phone as rooted.

Comment: @Robert Yes, I have to install Play Services to get the app. Will I have this same problem with other OS such as GrapheneOS?

Comment: This is the modern reality of "romming" I am afraid... You will always run into some apps that either just won't work, or require a fair amount of faking out with 3rd party tools/apps to make work due to the checks they perform. Pretty much any other ROM except stock with a locked bootloader will likely give the same result with the app in question.

Comment: Very frustrating. I used to buy a phone every 6 years or so. I installed LineageOS to this phone because the same app was telling me I couldn't access certain features due to the security date being too old, or something. Guess I should have gone into semiconductor manufacturing.

Comment: By installing Magisk and one of the [SafetyNet fix plugin versions](https://github.com/Displax/safetynet-fix/releases) (some times you need the latest version, some time an older one) you can bypass SafetyNet checks.